# Why can I not use manager.locationServicesEnabled()

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am checking if location services are enabled for the app. Looking at the code below, why can I not use "!manager.locationServicesEnabled()" since locationManager is of type CLLocationManager?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    enableLocationServices(manager: locationManager)

}

func enableLocationServices(manager: CLLocationManager) {

    manager.delegate = self

    if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you update your info.plist file, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are asking why you must use `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` and not `manager.locationServicesEnabled()` then the answer is simply that `locationServicesEnabled` is a type method and must be called on the class, not an instance of the class.

When looking at the documentation for a method or property, if it starts with `class` or `static` then you call it on the class, struct, or enum directly. If it doesn't start with `class` or `static`, then you call it on a specific instance of the class, struct, or enum.

Comment: That makes complete sense now. Thanks!